# What is the HTML tag "div" short for?

Tags: html

What is the div in the  `<div>`  tag short for?  Is it "division"?  I've looked around Google and SO and haven't found an answer.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: Curiosity.

Comment: @Daniel - what on earth makes you think a division can't be semantic?

Comment: @annakata: A <div> is not semantic...it has to do with containment and layout, not meaning. You might be able to make the argument that <span> is semantic...but only a weak one. Semantic tags are <strong>, <em>, etc.

Comment: Just because something doesn't apply semantics doesn't mean it can't have its own semantics. Everything has some form of semantics. Only certain things _apply_ semantics to other things. Semantic elements are elements that supply semantic meaning to their context. It doesn't mean that other elements don't deserve their own semantic meaning.

Comment: <div> does not apply semantics but has its own semantic: short for document division

Answer (score 206, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#block

> Document division

Answer (score 18):

Division. The DIV tag is is designed to allow you to define ***"divisions"*** of a page (or to "***divide*** a page into logical containers").

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that the definition of div is completely different in HTML5.

> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element

Comment: I think this article is referring to something a bit different than what the OP is asking for. cdmckay is asking about the meaning of the word (or name) "div", not the meaning or usage of the <div> element in an html document.